# How to remove pdfannotextractor copyright text from the generated pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texlive, pax

Hi I generated a pdf with the help of pdflatex and pdfannotextractor.

First of all, thanks for `pdfannotextractor` this helped me to generate a pdf without missing any links in the inlcuded pdf.

After generating the pdf, I saw a additional page which contains the pdfannotextractor copyright text. How to remove this page.

[image: PDFannotExtractor copyright processing text]

I need to remove this page.

My pdfannotextractor version is `PDFAnnotExtractor 2012/04/18 v0.1l`

Comment: Copy the contents of the .pax-file created by the script in your question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the question is upated with .pax file content.

Comment: Your script must be faulty and inject the output of the  PDFAnnotExtractor in your doc-code. Probably unrelated: I wouldn't call `pdflatex user/join-template`  but switch into the user folder first and then call `pdflatex join-template`.